# How to generate token based on few fields

Tags: php, laravel, token

I am in need of generating a token for users to cancel their membership. Now  I need multiple fields in token table.

Currently I am using str_rand(26) but there is a possibility that it would generate a string that is already in a databse because when user click on cancel link I get the table entry based on token so it is not a good model.

What I want is to provide few fields and based on those fields a token is generated and when I receive that token I can get those IDS back and access that particular row.

```
For example generate_token(user_id + payment_id + registration_id)
```

OR if there is better work around for such task than please do share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want is to provide few fields and based on those fields a token is generated and when I receive that token I can get those IDS back and access that particular row.

This won't work with a token as they are either a hash or random. If it is a hash of these three ids you can calculate the hash from the ids but it should nearly be impossible (hashes are not reverse calculable) to get the ids out of the hash.

I would say generating a token for the unsubscribe process and then then removing the data record with that specific token is the correct way.
The probability that two identical (if long enough eg. 32 characters) tokens are generated is almost negligible. To add, the token only exists for the time period when the user asked to unsubscribe until he confirms the action.

For example a 32 character [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) such as `21EC2020-3AEA-4069-A2DD-08002B30309D` is considered as globally unique!

Comment: Have you used this method in a system where payments are involved. If yes how big was user database?

Comment: No I did't but I did use GUIDs on larger projects without any problems. I don't understand what your concerns are when payments are involved?

Comment: No I am only afraid of getting  a prompt from customer that something wrong in the system. Let me generate and check that and I will accept your answer. Thanks for your help.